# Left mouse click trigger the research (F3 Key) Window 10

Tags: windows-10

In window 10

I have activated by mistake, and I don't know how, the research (F3 key) when I left click with the mouse and touch any letters of the keyboard in any software.

Someone have an idea how to disactivate this ?

Comment: Does it happen in all applications, or only one (and which one)?

Comment: All applications

Comment: Does it happen when [booting in Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234).

Comment: It doesn't make it under Safe mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not happen when booting in Safe Mode, where third-party programs are
disabled. This means that the problem is caused by some third-party product
that is installed on the computer and is set to startup automatically
with Windows.

Download and install
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns),
which is the best tool for managing startup programs.

Run Autoruns to see all the startup programs in the "Everything" tab.
You can here disable and enable programs by clicking their check-mark.

I would start with disabling products that have some relationship to the keyboard.
If you cannot guess which one is it, you will need to do it
the hard way by unchecking them in bunches and rebooting each time.
Re-enable those that cause no problem.

When you find the troublesome product, you may either leave it as not-startup
and call it manually when needed, or uninstall it completely if not needed,
or find some setting that prevents it from taking over the mouse,
or look for a more recent version of it that behaves better.

Comment: Thanks so much. I found out it came form the software that controlling the wireless keyboard and mouse. Maybe something in cache, after having cleaning the keyboard with cloth. After resetting the keyboard and the mouse, the problem looks gone.